# With iOS UIKIT can you call dismiss() before presentation is complete?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have several cases in my apps where asynchronous behavior could lead to a situation where dismiss() is called a very short time after calling present().

Consider this code sample to illustrate:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
[ do some work here ]
alert.dismiss(animated: true)
```

The amount of time between the present() and dismiss() could be long or short, possibly less than a millisecond if there is no work to do. If the work is completed immediately will it result in a runtime error?

If the call to dismiss() should be delayed until the presentation is complete, how would I code that?

Note that I cannot use the completion handler of the present() API because dismiss() is called from a separate completion handler.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem because all your UI activity has to happen on the main thread.  That means your `dismiss` isn't really interrupting the `present`.

Try it for yourself by simply running the no-work version of your own code.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
alert.dismiss(animated: true)
```

When I do that, I see the alert flash onto the screen and immediately disappear...no error.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what your `[do some work]` is...

Both `present()` and `dismiss()` must be called on the main thread, so presumably `[do some work]` is running on a background / async thread.

This (as Phillip notes):

```
@objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
    print("Tap")
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // [do some work]
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Will present and immediately dismiss the Alert controller, with no errors.

This, however:

```
@objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
    print("Tap")
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    // [do some work]
    // NEVER DO THIS!!!!
    // but, for demonstration purposes...
    sleep(2)    // sleep 2 seconds - freezes app
    
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Will lock execution of your app. You won't even see the Alert show up until *after* the `sleep()` has finished.

So, assuming you have a `doSomeWork()` function that runs async or background thread, just make sure your call to dismiss includes:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

---

**Edit** - a couple additional notes...

***IF*** you have another thread which may call `dismiss()` independently, you *may* run into problems.

For example, this code will add a button and start a timer, which will fire every 0.1 seconds. If you tap the button to present the alert, you will likely see:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller ... while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

class PresDisViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: [])
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(b)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // set a timer to call dismiss every 0.1 seconds
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerDismiss), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }

    @objc func timerDismiss() -> Void {
        print(#function)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        print("Tap")
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
        
}
```

You can avoid that by making sure the alert is neither being presented nor dismissed:

```
class PresDisViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: [])
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(b)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // set a timer to call dismiss every 0.1 seconds
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerDismiss), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }

    @objc func timerDismiss() -> Void {
        print(#function)

        // if there IS a presented view controller
        //    AND
        // it is NOT in the process of being presented
        //    AND
        // it is NOT in the process of being dismissed
        
        if let v = self.presentedViewController, !v.isBeingPresented, !v.isBeingDismissed {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        print("Tap")
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
        
}
```